# Add prefix to properties names using ogr2ogr sqlite

Tags: geojson, ogr2ogr, sqlite

I am using ogr2ogr to create a geojson file with props from sqlite Db with this
`ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -sql "SELECT * FROM censusblockgroups2 shp INNER JOIN 'output-z' csv ON csv.name = shp.censusblockgroup" joined_output.geojson myjoindb.db`

It will create a geojson with this structure

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "SELECT",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 1, "attr": "ipsum" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -78.653, 35.7874 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 2, "attr": "lorem" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -78.6298, 35.7873 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 3, "attr": "ipsum" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -78.6408, 35.7795 ] } }
]
}
```

But is it possible to create a prefix for `properties` name depending on SQL table name? like
`"properties": { "id": 3, "output-z_attr": "ipsum" }` or by alias name
`"properties": { "id": 3, "csv_attr": "ipsum" }` or even like
`"properties": { "id": 3, "csv": {"name":"ipsum", other props from table} }`

Comment: Easiest is to rewrite SQL `select attr AS csv_attr, attr_2 AS csv_attr2...`.  Unfortunately the ease of select * is lost.